# No Sql server o "GO" tem a mesma função do ponto e virgula?

Tags: mysql, sql

Para que serve a palavra reservado "GO" no `Sql Server`, ao gerar um script usando `Sql Server Management` é sempre gerado com a palavra reservado "GO" no final das instruções, porem se eu pego a mesma query e a executo sem a palavra a "GO" ela é executada normalmente.

Eu compreendo a utilização do ponto e virgula no `MySql`, eu entendo que ao se executar uma query utilizando um sistema com interface gráfica este mesmo sistema a executa com o ponto e virgula no final, mesmo que eu não a coloque, e compreendo também que ela serve para separar as instruções, no `Sql Server` a palavra `"GO"` tem a mesma função do ponto e virgula? E se ele é responsável por outra tarefa, qual seria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Instruções de utilitários do SQL Server – GO

O SQL Server fornece comandos que não são instruções Transact-SQL, mas que são reconhecidos pelos utilitários sqlcmd e osql e pelo Editor de Códigos SQL Server Management Studio. Estes comandos podem ser usados para facilitar a legibilidade e a execução de lotes e scripts.

O GO sinaliza o término de um lote de instruções Transact-SQL para os utilitários do SQL Server.

## O GO vai alem de um ponto e virgula

Podemos ver isso neste exemplo

```
SELECT DB_NAME();  
SELECT USER_NAME();  
GO 2
```

Perceba que há um "2" na frente do "GO", isso quer dizer que as duas instruções acima serão executadas duas vezes

Veja este outro exemplo

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DECLARE @NmbrPeople int  
SELECT @NmbrPeople = COUNT(*)  
FROM Person.Person;  
PRINT 'The number of people as of ' +  
      CAST(GETDATE() AS char(20)) + ' is ' +  
      CAST(@NmbrPeople AS char (10));  
GO
```

Onde temos dois blocos de instruções, onde temos no segundo bloco com variáveis locais, que serão utilizada apenas neste contexto já que foi limitada pelo "GO"

[Fonte](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017)